# Idiomatic List Wrapper

Tags: google-app-engine, python

In Google App Engine, I make lists of referenced properties much like this:

```
class Referenced(BaseModel):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Thing(BaseModel):
    foo_keys = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        if attrname == 'foos':
            return Referenced.get(self.foo_keys)
        else:
            return BaseModel.__getattr__(self, attrname)
```

This way, someone can have a `Thing` and say `thing.foos` and get something legitimate out of it.  The problem comes when somebody says `thing.foos.append(x)`.  This will not save the added property because the underlying list of keys remains unchanged.  So I quickly wrote this solution to make it easy to append keys to a list:

```
class KeyBackedList(list):
    def __init__(self, key_class, key_list):
        list.__init__(self, key_class.get(key_list))
        self.key_class = key_class
        self.key_list = key_list

    def append(self, value):
        self.key_list.append(value.key())
        list.append(self, value)

class Thing(BaseModel):
    foo_keys = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        if attrname == 'foos':
            return KeyBackedList(Thing, self.foo_keys)
        else:
            return BaseModel.__getattr__(self, attrname)
```

This is great for proof-of-concept, in that it works exactly as expected when calling `append`.  However, I would never give this to other people, since they might mutate the list in other ways (`thing[1:9] = whatevs` or `thing.sort()`).  Sure, I could go define all the `__setslice__` and whatnot, but that seems to leave me open for obnoxious bugs.  However, that is the best solution I can come up with.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do (something in the Python library perhaps)?  Or am I going about this the wrong way and trying to make things too smooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify things like this, you shouldn't be changing `__getattr__` on the model; instead, you should write a [custom Property class](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Custom-Datastore-Properties-1-DerivedProperty).

As you've observed, though, creating a workable 'ReferenceListProperty' is difficult and involved, and there are many subtle edge cases. I would recommend sticking with the list of keys, and fetching the referenced entities in your code when needed.

Comment: I really like the custom Property class, but I also like the idea of calling `append` on my own wrapper.  It lets me do things like check that the type of key you're adding to the list is actually what should be there, since directly adding to the key list doesn't give me that type safety.  To me, calling `thing.foos.append(f)` is more natural than `thing.foo_keys.append(f.key())` or wrapping it like `thing.add_foo(f)`.

Comment: @Travis You can still do that - my point in the first part of my answer is that you shouldn't be modifying the model's `__getattr__`, but should instead be writing a custom property class to achieve the same effect with its `__get__` method. Regarding whether you do automatic dereferencing or not, that's up to you, but I maintain my position that it's a) Very complicated to get right, and b) doesn't gain you much. Further, it obscures the actual datastore operations involved, whilst dereferencing them yourself makes that clearer, and allows you to be as efficient as possible.